# Problema al cerrar sesion usando la gema de devise ( "No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out")

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy creando un proyecto de red social y para ello estoy usando la gema de devise,todo va bien (registro usuarios, creo post) pero al cerrar la sesión del usuario me sale este mensaje de error:

> "No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

y pues el codigo que conduce a ello es:

`"<li><%= link_to "Cerrar Sesion", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>`

Comment: como hacen para colocar esos fondos y estilos de letra por aca...?estoy empezando, mi pregunta aparece con esos estilos porque alguien me hizo el favor de editarla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que funcionen verbos http no convencionales (como `DELETE` en el caso que usa devise), debes agregar las librerías de [unobstructive javascript para Jquery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) a tu `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

O si no, prueba a abrir tu archivo `config/initializers/devise.rb`, buscar:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

y cambiarlo por:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

luego simplemente remueves `method: :delete` de tu link:

```
<li><%= link_to "Cerrar Sesion", destroy_user_session_path %></li>
```

Comment: ciertamente ya tengo instalada la gema jquery-rails (4.1.0) y tambien por defecto ya estaba agregado //= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs a mi archivo application.js. con ello, me sale el error mencionado.

Comment: @JuanCarlosAldana revisa mi actualización

Comment: Gracias Alter Lagos, la actualización que hiciste en tu respuesta resolvió por completo el problema que presentaba al cerrar sesión, ahora si lo hace de manera efectiva, y ademas si le doy click hacia atrás no me lleva a la pagina de sesión del usuario que la cerro, sino a la de login, lo cual me parece perfecto ya que se garantiza la seguridad para los usuarios. Agradezco la ayuda, soy nuevo en esta plataforma y no pensé que fuese tan efectiva.